# What is sharedInfo in x963DerivedSymmetricKey when creating a symmetric key for opening and closing a sealed box on iOS?

Tags: ios, security, cryptography, aes, aes-gcm

I am reading this Apple documentation and trying to apply it:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cryptokit/sharedsecret

It says:

> The shared secret isn’t suitable as a symmetric cryptographic key (SymmetricKey) by itself. However, you use it to generate a key by calling either the hkdfDerivedSymmetricKey(using:salt:sharedInfo:outputByteCount:) or x963DerivedSymmetricKey(using:sharedInfo:outputByteCount:) method of the shared secret. After the other party does the same, then you both share a symmetric key suitable for creating a message authentication code like HMAC, or for opening and closing a sealed box with a cipher like ChaChaPoly or AES.

When I click on the link for `x963DerivedSymmetricKey(using:sharedInfo:outputByteCount:)`:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cryptokit/sharedsecret/x963derivedsymmetrickey(using:sharedinfo:outputbytecount:)

It says:

> sharedInfo: The shared information to use for key derivation.

> outputByteCount: The length in bytes of resulting symmetric key.

I am confused about these 2 parameters. What exactly is supposed to be passed for `sharedInfo` and `outputByteCount`?

The only example I could find is here:

https://gist.github.com/mehmeteminkartal/e2d1ee56526dc032b7257aef80c40d16

But I think this example might be incorrect as it passes `bobPublicKey.rawRepresentation` for `sharedInfo` for both `alice_key` and `bobs_key`. Also not sure why it passes `16` for `outputByteCount`.

Can someone explain these?

Comment: The shared info is exactly that ; some bytes that both parties know to generate the symmetric key. It should be a secret, so a public key is a bad choice. 16 bytes of output in your example would correspond to a 128 bit shared key. 32 bytes of output would be a 256 bit key

Comment: The shared info is often the result of the elliptic curve or modp Diffie-Hellman key agreement calculation. It should be a high-entropy secret. For low-entropy secrets like passwords/passphrases, a different kind of KDF specifically designed for the purpose should be used, like the modern argon2 KDF or the older but still adequate PBKDF2.

Comment: @Paulw11 In that GitHub example, it first generates `shared_secret_bob` and `shared_secret_alice`. Aren't those secret too? Then what's the need for `shared info`? How would Bob and Alice know of this shared info before hand?

Comment: That is part of the challenge with symmetric key encryption; you need some way to exchange the secret so that both parties know it.  Often asymmetric encryption is used to exchange the key for symmetric encryption. This is because symmetric key algorithms are typically more efficient at encrypting large amounts of data. The less efficient asymmetric encryption is used to exchange the relatively small key secret

Comment: `sharedSecretWithKeyAgreement` is a method that generates a shared secret using a public private key pair.  It is discussed in [this article](https://www.andyibanez.com/posts/common-cryptographic-operations-with-cryptokit/). Since the public keys can be distributed openly but the corresponding private key is required to generate the  shared secret, it makes the symmetric encryption possible. And there is, indeed, an error in the gist you linked to. Bob should use Alice's public key and vice versa.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for that link. That link actually mentions one of the questions I had about `sharedInfo`. If you scroll down to the "Key Agreement" section and look at the example after "...can start sharing data encrypted using this key" line, it does a `hkdfDerivedSymmetricKey` which is similar to my `x963DerivedSymmetricKey` as both require a `sharedInfo`. In that example, they pass `Data()` as the value to both which is basically an empty data buffer. Is that okay/secure? An empty data buffer can be considered "shared" and doesn't require sharing beforehand. But is that secure?

Comment: In this case it is ok because they have used `sharedSecretFromKeyAgreement` which is used to determine the shared secret

Comment: @Paulw11 ok thanks. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6553/what-information-to-include-is-the-info-input-for-hkdf also has a nice explanation